# SMS Retrieve API react native

Tags: react-native, sms-retriever-api

> > SMS retrieve API

I am working with a react native android application in this application I am reading a OTP that is sent from the SMS gateway I am using SMS Read permission the application is working fine but when I am trying to upload it in google play it is rejecting it because of SMS Read permission. I have read about the substitute and that is SMS retrieve API can anyone help me how to implement it in react native.

Comment: I am recieving the otp message autmatically because we have phone no saved in the database so only i need to read the automatically